# Merge date and time, find the time difference in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data set and there are some date and hour attributes. Here is the sample, then I will explain what I want to do;

| date1 | hour1 | date2 | hour2 | date3 | hour3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-03-16 00:00:00 | 16:20:00 | 2014-03-16 00:00:00 | 20:20:03 | 2014-03-16 00:00:00 | 22:12:34 |
| 2014-04-22 00:00:00 | 10:20:00 | 2014-04-22 00:00:00 | 15:20:03 | 2014-04-22 00:00:00 | 20:12:34 |
| 2015-03-12 00:00:00 | 16:20:00 | 2015-03-12 00:00:00 | 20:20:03 | 2015-03-12 00:00:00 | 22:12:34 |

**We know** event1 happens before event2 (event1 -> event2 -> event3)

But as you see, in the date attributes, time section is not correct yet we have hour attributes for each. What I want to do; I want to correct them by using hour attributes then find the difference between these two dates and create new attributes that gives the time difference as hours.

Sample for above table;

| event2_time |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 4 |

I tried to merge hour to date and create a new attribute like this but it doesn't work.(my goal is actually correct the date value and get rid of the hour attribute)

```
trainTable <- trainTable %>%
   mutate("newParam" = as.POSIXct(paste(alert_date, alert_hour), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I could use some help, thanks in advance.

**Data**

```
structure(list(alert_date = structure(c(1394928000, 1395014400, 
1395014400, 1395187200, 1395273600, 1395014400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), alert_hour = c("16:15:00", "20:53:00", "12:55:00", 
"14:22:00", "12:07:00", "17:48:00"), firstInterv_date = structure(c(1394928000, 
1395014400, 1395014400, 1395187200, 1395273600, 1395014400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), firstInterv_hour = c("16:35:00", "21:05:00", "13:10:00", 
"14:42:00", "12:07:00", "18:08:00"), extinction_date = structure(c(1394928000, 
1395014400, 1395014400, 1395187200, 1395273600, 1395014400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), extinction_hour = c("17:47:00", "22:46:00", "15:30:00", 
"15:25:00", "13:14:00", "21:10:00")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I also tried to create a function that would take date and hour as params and changes date's hour section and returns the date. But I couldn't create the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution using `mapply`. It uses `strsplit` to split the date from the hours.

```
dat <- as.data.frame( dat ) # tibbles are cool but sometimes very restrictive, so changing to data.frame here

dat_new <- data.frame( setNames( mapply( function(x,y){
  tmp <- sapply( strsplit( as.character(dat[,x]), " "), function(z) z[1] );
  list( as.POSIXct( paste(tmp,dat[,y] ) ) ) },
  grep("date", colnames(dat)), grep("hour", colnames(dat)) ), 
  c("a","b","c") ) )

dat_new$b - dat_new$a
Time differences in secs
[1] 1200  720  900 1200    0 1200

# if you need tibbles convert back if you need
as_tibble( dat_new )
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  a                   b                   c                  
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2014-03-16 16:15:00 2014-03-16 16:35:00 2014-03-16 17:47:00
2 2014-03-17 20:53:00 2014-03-17 21:05:00 2014-03-17 22:46:00
3 2014-03-17 12:55:00 2014-03-17 13:10:00 2014-03-17 15:30:00
4 2014-03-19 14:22:00 2014-03-19 14:42:00 2014-03-19 15:25:00
5 2014-03-20 12:07:00 2014-03-20 12:07:00 2014-03-20 13:14:00
6 2014-03-17 17:48:00 2014-03-17 18:08:00 2014-03-17 21:10:00
```

##### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(alert_date = structure(c(1394928000, 1395014400, 
1395014400, 1395187200, 1395273600, 1395014400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), alert_hour = c("16:15:00", "20:53:00", "12:55:00", 
"14:22:00", "12:07:00", "17:48:00"), firstInterv_date = structure(c(1394928000, 
1395014400, 1395014400, 1395187200, 1395273600, 1395014400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), firstInterv_hour = c("16:35:00", "21:05:00", "13:10:00", 
"14:42:00", "12:07:00", "18:08:00"), extinction_date = structure(c(1394928000, 
1395014400, 1395014400, 1395187200, 1395273600, 1395014400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), extinction_hour = c("17:47:00", "22:46:00", "15:30:00", 
"15:25:00", "13:14:00", "21:10:00")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I still don't know how to correct time section of my date attributes yet I will get rid of them anyway and yes this works for the difference. Thank you for your answer and help :)

Comment: @Flardryn The dat_new data frame has the correct POSIXct date time objects. Do you want to get rid of the time or date part?

Comment: Yes you are right they are correct now I was still thinking the merging and manipulating part. I will remove dates. Btw it works fine with your data but when I try to apply my data set, I get an error.  `strsplit(firstSix[, x], " ") : non-character argument` I've checked my date classes everything seems fine :/  @Andre Wildberg

Comment: @Flardryn That's because in my dataset they're just characters not Time objects. You can fix that by doing `as.character(dat[,x])` or in your case `as.character(firstSix[, x])` inside the `strsplit`.

Comment: `as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` this time, I couldn't convert it to char @Andre Wildberg

Comment: @Flardryn I put it in the code. See edit.

Comment: Ok I tried the same but I am getting the above error. When I check my hour classes it shows difftime. But they are not the diff they are exact times. I can't use the same code with my data @Andre Wildberg

Comment: @Flardryn Please `dput( head(data) )` your data to your question as normally required, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) (dput part) if you have questions.

Comment: Added @Andre Wildberg

Comment: @Flardryn Thanks for posting the data. See edit.

Comment: Yes, now I have it. Sorry it took some come and go I'll require more details on my posts next time. Thank you so much for your time and help! @Andre Wildberg

Comment: @Flardryn Cool, glad it works now!